# How to create a SQL query that generates a JSON array of two different objects?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, for-json

I need to generate a JSON array containing two dissimilar objects:

```
[
    {
        "command": "setcontext",
        "recordtype": "client",
        "recordid": 1030
    },
    {
        "command": "gotodq",
        "usercode": "react_webuser_debtor_details"
    }
]
```

I'm able to generate the two objects separate by using:

```
SELECT 
    'setcontext' AS command, 'client' AS recordtype, 1030 AS recordid 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

SELECT 
    'gotodq' AS command, 'react_webuser_debtor_details' AS usercode 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

but I can't find out how to join those two statements into one to get the array.

Obviously I can concatenate both as strings appending the array markers but I'm curious on how a "pure" SQL to JSON solution would look...

Comment: @marc_s See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217234/why-is-placing-the-tag-name-in-the-question-title-bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2022 and Azure SQL, you can use the `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_OBJECT` functions

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'command':'setcontext',
      'recordtype':'client',
      'recordid':1030
    ),
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'command':'gotodq',
      'usercode':'react_webuser_debtor_details'
    )
);
```

In older versions, you can't use those. Also `JSON_ARRAY_AGG` also isn't available.

You could just concatenate them. (Use `STRING_AGG` if you have an undefined number of items.)

```sql
SELECT '[' + (
    SELECT 
      'setcontext' AS command, 'client' AS recordtype, 1030 AS recordid 
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) + ',' + (
    SELECT 
      'gotodq' AS command, 'react_webuser_debtor_details' AS usercode 
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  );
```

Or you could do it as a `UNION ALL`, but then columns with the same name would need to be the same data type.

```sql
SELECT 
  'setcontext' AS command,
  'client' AS recordtype,
  1030 AS recordid,
  NULL AS usercode

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'gotodq',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'react_webuser_debtor_details'

FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/x-F12CuL)

Comment: Looks nice... but my compatibility level is SQLServer 2019 ;-( Thank You anyway!

Comment: OK see other options

Comment: Probably the "UNION ALL" is the best SQL2019 solution but I want to stress in my code that the returning objects are different so I'll use the concatenation. TY!